# Using PHP namespaces on a subnamespace

Tags: php, namespaces

Good day. I'm working on an example to understand exactly what namespces are, and what are their limitations.
I have this structure (windows):

> D:\server\sistemas\tests\phpNS\exec.php
>
> D:\server\sistemas\tests\phpNS\Extra\Call.php
>
> D:\server\sistemas\tests\phpNS\Extra\exec.php --> (copy of the other one)
>
> D:\server\sistemas\tests\phpNS\Lib\Base.php

Code for each one:

## exec.php

```
<?php 
spl_autoload_register();

$a = new Extra\Call();
?>
```

## Call.php

```
<?php
namespace Extra{
    spl_autoload_register();

    class Call{
        public function __construct(){
            $inst = new \Libs\Base();
            var_dump($inst);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

## Base.php

```
<?php
namespace Libs{
    class Base{
        public $dac;
        public $doc;
        public function __construct(){

        }
    }
}
?>
```

If I work under this scenario, everything is totally ok. The problem is when I execute Extra\exec.php

## Extra\exec.php

```
<?php 
namespace Extra{
    spl_autoload_register();

    $a = new Call();
}
?>
```

It's supposed that the filesystem context of this file is Extra so that's why I'm using that namespace but is not working. I got this error.

> Fatal error: spl_autoload(): Class Extra\Call could not be loaded in D:\server\sistemas\tests\phpNS\Extra\exec.php on line 5

Then I remember php classes are called by a trailing backslash (\Iterator) so i tried this too:

## Extra\exec.php

```
<?php
    spl_autoload_register();

    $a = new \Extra\Call();

?>
```

But I got the same result... What am I doing wrong, and what should I do if I want to use this file in this or in any n-depth directory?

Comment: Would using one of the `autoloader components` help you? e.g. [The PSR-4 Class Loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/psr4_class_loader.html). Also: [Aura.Autoload : Provides a full PSR-4 and limited PSR-0 autoloader](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Autoload/tree/2.x). Both simplify managing `autoloading` of classes. I have used both and currently using `Aura`.

Comment: Hmm it seems that it could work. But it means I need to make use of symfony to get that right? I just make sure that I can use namespaces at any n-depth directory level, because if I need to use htaccess rewriterules feature from a blank index.php, and with this problem, I'm not capable to redirect to a file into the structure of the project without get a not loading class error.

Comment: Im sorry Ryan, maybe I'm doing something wrong. i've rewrite my code on exec.php (this good one)

 $dir = _ _DIR_ _."/Libs/Aura.Autoload-2.x/src/Loader.php";
 require_once($dir);
 $loader = new \Aura\Autoload\Loader;

 $loader->register();
 $loader->addPrefix('Extra\Call', '\Extra\Call.php');

 $a = new Extra\Call();

I followed the instructions, and is loading the Aura, or at least, I think is loading, but is not loading my class. Can you helping me with this please?

Comment: [Zipped Source code for a working `Aura autoloader` on windows](http://ge.tt/537GA1P2/v/0?c). Download and unzip to any directory. The only file that you should need to change is: `__bootstrap__.php` in the root directory. You need to change the `APP_ROOT_DIR` define to the path where that directory is. The `test_loader*.php` files should then start to load the classes in the `classes` directory. I will supply complete explanation later - if required. The files are fairly well commented. maybe?

Comment: +1 Thank you very much Ryan for your effort and time, I appreciate it too much. I'll checking it, as soon as I can be out of the office. At the moment I saw some code, it looks good. I'll post you later. Thanks again =)

Comment: there is no rush - I ain't going anywhere and there is a lot to appreciate. Just post comments as and when required. They will be answered. The code provided is  'minimum code' that provides enough places to separate 'boiler plate' code / components from your `application` code and classes. The code has been tested and works here.

Answer (score 2):

First off, it's not recommended you use `namespace` declarations as blocks. It's preferred simply declare the `namespace` and then go into your classes and place one class per file. This is how you would declare `\Extra\Call`

```
namespace Extra;

class Call{
    public function __construct(){
        $inst = new \Libs\Base();
        var_dump($inst);
    }
}
```

You typically use `spl_autoload_register();` with the name of your callable function but you haven't provided any functions that could act as an autoloader. Your autoload function should have as its sole argument the name of the class you're trying to load. it should then find your class file and `include` or `require` that file. Here's an example [from the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't have any sense. Because I'm not working with just a class Im instanciating a class inside another. Even when it works I still depending of require and/or include(_once). Because if I'm working with 1000 classes I should load 1000 classes on the autoload function... means we're back to the old times just with "tidy" code, but in performance i don't get any better.

Comment: @Artynok First off, autoload only loads files as you need them. You can't tell me you need 1000 classes for every file. Second, you can set your autoload to follow your directory structure. Lastly, this isn't a performance thing so much as a sanity thing. I never have to guess where to find my classes.

Comment: first off namespaces are not blocks? yes they can be used as blocks and is shown in [the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php)
Second, as you explained that autooload function use one required file or class... what happe if I need many classes or files for that case?
Lastly you just answered with theory you never used my case to try to explain how to use that

Comment: @Artynok fair enough. You can use blocking for multiple classes. But the same manual page notes this is not a recommended practice. As for needing multiple classes, that's what autoloading does. It loads all the classes you need and no more. As to not providing you with a more concrete example, I can't comment without more data

Answer (score 0):

given the facts that Machavity needs explicitly I give "more concrete example" here is the result of his answer:
as you said I need to use to register an autoload function inside of the spl_autoload_register so ok i did that and it works... but JUST for the exec.php that is in the root place.

## exec.php

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include $class . '.php';
});

$a = new Extra\Call();
```

But this is not working for the Extra\exec.php. I had to get the basename and use the namespace to load the class. But it keeps failing cause is asking me for non existant Extra\Libs\Base.php

## Extra\exec.php

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $f = basename($class);
    include __DIR__."\\".$f . '.php';
});

$a = new \Extra\Call();
```

It means I need to get all the root structure depending on each location and do many ugly tricks. As I said you never used my case even to get this conclusion, so I've marked this your answer as not useful.